# query to select time range out of datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to identify current position of a mobile user.
I have latitude and longitude along with timestamps in a table "Mobilelocations".

```
      latitude  longitude             time
    12.91207267 77.6323475      2015-12-10 21:47:25
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 22:18:39
    12.91207267 77.6323475      2015-12-10 02:37:14
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 03:43:53
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 03:22:31
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 03:51:10
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 04:35:21
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 05:34:00
    12.91207268 77.6323434      2015-12-10 18:48:06
    12.91207268 77.6323455      2015-12-10 19:02:08
    76.58753525 77.6323486      2015-12-10 19:02:25
    87.34327624 77.6327356      2015-12-10 19:10:45
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 18:45:07
    12.91207268 77.6323475      2015-12-10 18:45:57
```

Wrote the following JPQL query for retrieving latitude, longitude and time from the "MobileLocations" table. Time chosen between 9pm to 7am. Expected to

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT loc FROM MobileLocations loc WHERE CAST(loc.time as time)>= '21:00:00' or CAST(loc.time as time)<='07:00:00'");
```

But seems it doesn't work as getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: < near line 1, column 212 [SELECT NEW com.vishwas.dto.mobile.MobileLocationsDto (loc.latitude, loc.longitude,loc.time) FROM com.vishwas.entity.mobile.MobileLocations loc where CAST(loc.time as time)>= '21:00:00' or CAST(loc.time as time)=<'07:00:00'
```

Comment: Which DB are you using?  SQL Server, Access, etc.  **Algo** - denoting pain: algometer, algophobia? :p

Comment: @Darren: using MySQL server.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Try `CAST(loc.time as time) <= '07:00:00'` instead of `CAST(loc.time as time)=<'07:00:00'`

Comment: @fancyPants : error persists even after that

Answer (score 0):

It will work without using the cast function also. Try this:

```
SELECT loc FROM MobileLocations loc WHERE loc.time between '21:00:00 00:00:00' and '07:00:00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: tried directly in Navicat DB tool(changing corresponding table and fields names), got this: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as time >= '21:00:00' or loc.time as time <= '07:00:00'' at line 1

Comment: I tried myself this before, it works but doesn't give intended result. I need time between 9 pm to 7 am. and when I do "between '21:00:00' and '07:00:00' " it gives NO RESULT but no error even, meaning as if there is no such data exists where there are in practice.

Comment: It may be because of datetime . You checked based on date only, included time check now.

Comment: it isn't. Can we replace with any database independent query for the same, i.e. without CAST()/CONVERT()?

Comment: Are you not getting the correct data or getting some error?